# Angular2- Routing to new component in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am trying to run a function when a button is clicked that will prep a variable and then at the end of the function redirect to another component and pass that variable. (I want functionality similar to the RouterLink in HTML but from the typescript)
I already know how to get the function to run and prep the variable but do not know how to send that variable to a new route (component) from the typescript.

Comment: Will you please share the code , how do you do that url in front side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add `(click)="myFunction()"` on your component HTML.
2. Import the Angular Router service in your component: `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`
3. Inject the router in your component constructor like this: `constructor( private router: Router, ...) { }`
4. And then define `myFunction` such as:

   ```
   myFunction(){
     this.router.navigate(['/myPath']);
   }
   ```